# Are all animals that end in "-e" feminine?

Tags: noun

I am newbie to the German language, but I have noticed that all animal names that end with letter "e" are feminine, and form their plural by adding -n at the end. Is this true?
If not give me some examples please.

Comment: _"but I have noticed that all animal names that end with letter "e" are feminine"_ Your _observation_ was wrong. The ending _e_ isn't a general indication of _feminine_.

Comment: If you are asking about the actual gender (sex): Aninal names are often used generically without implying a gender. Der Hund can be male or female, and you can clarify by using Rüde (male) or Hündin (female). If you're asking about grammatical gender: most nouns ending in "e" are female, not limited to animals.

Comment: @Robert Like "Affe" and "Löwe"...

Comment: @tofro That's why I wrote "most", not "all".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are a few counterexamples: der Hase, der Löwe, der Riese, der Junge. In general, though, you can safely add an -n to form the plural (just watch out for "das Knie, die Knie").

You might enjoy [this article](https://www.thoughtco.com/tricky-masculine-nouns-in-german-1444484).

Comment: der Hase,der Junge are not animals

Comment: Der Hase is certainly an animal, by any definition. Der Junge is arguably also an animal, according to biologists - a mammal and a primate, a young male of the species Homo sapiens.

Comment: Riese und Junge sind keine Tiere im Sinne von Tierarten, sowenig wie Russe oder Komparse. Die generische Form für Junge ist, wenn es um menschliche Jungen geht, Mensch. Das Lerchenjunge ist eine Lerche. Hase und Löwe können wir aber gelten lassen. :) Knie dagegen wieder nicht.

Comment: @userunknown "das Lerchenjunge"?.  Wirklich? Fast so gut wie "das Kuhjunge". Das *Wolfsjunge* ist OK, aber wenn wir "Küken", "Kalb" o.Ä. nehmen können, würden wir nicht "Junge" sagen.

Comment: Du meinst das Huhnjunge!